# Apache rewrite rule

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I want to redirect "http://localhost/b.html"  --> "http://localhost/a.html"
I tried RewriteRule for that. But somehow it is not working for me.

I am using apache2 and my httpd.conf contains:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/b.html$ http://localhost/a.html
```

When I tri "http://localhost/a.html" It shows me the web page. But when I triend "http://localhost/b.html" apache2/error_log says "file does not exist: b.html"
Does any setting missing to enable rewrite_module?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in your RewriteRule. this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/b.html$ /a.html [L]
```

1. <strike>the rule match (`^b.html$`) must not include the starting slash.</strike> (this works in .htaccess, but not in server config)
2. the rewrite target should be a relative URI if possible (i.e. on the same host)
3. the rule should end with a directive "what to do" - in this case `[L]`eave processing (no more rules will be processed)

Comment: Also, when you're debugging rewrites, it is easier to put the rules into a .htaccess at DocumentRoot - no need to restart the server then.

Comment: 1. is for .htaccess - when you're in the .conf you need the /    2. agreed    3. You don't need this - having [L] when it's already the last rule does nothing

Comment: +1 Not sure why this got downvoted. The [L] isn't strictly required for the last rule in the file but it's good practice to have it anyway (so you don't have to remember to put it in when you add a new rule)

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked whether in your Apache configuration file (most likely httpd.conf) the  directive for the Alias or VirtualHost section:

```
AllowOverride All
```

I had the same problem of modrewrite not working because I had it off:

```
AllowOverride None
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have it inside the virtualhost section?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/b.html$ /a.html
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

It works now. Had to do two things:

1. Change "AllowOverride None" in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default to "AllowOverride All".
2. Put the rewrite rule in /var/www/.htaccess instead of httpd.conf

I am not sure why it does not works in httpd.conf. But it works after doing the above two things.

Comment: This is exactly what I answered ;-)