# Apache error 404 for subdomain with Codeigniter application

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I am trying to access subdomain url's in this web site

http://medica.mastertools.net/

but I always get:

```
The requested URL /logincheck was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/7.1.11 Server at medica.mastertools.net Port 80
```

I found out is not a server configuration because pointing to another folder, subdomains work, so probably something in Codeigniter is wrong.

In the route.php I have:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['logincheck'] = "home/logincheck";
```

and my controller:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

function logincheck()
{
    if(isset($_POST['strUsername']))
    {
        $blogin_ok = $this->logmodel->check_login($_POST['strUsername'], $_POST['strPassword']);
        if( $blogin_ok == 1)
        {
            $this->index();
        }
        else if ( $blogin_ok == 2 )
        {
            $this->makeFinalLayout('loginchose');
        }
        else
        {
          $_SESSION['loggin_msg'] = LOGINERRORMSG;
            $this->login();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->login();
    }
}
```

Comment: So the subdomain works but not `/logincheck`?

Comment: I found out now is not a server configuration because pointing to another folder subdomains work, so probably something in Codeigniter is wrong

Comment: only main domain works, /logincheck no

Comment: is there an .htaccesss file in the root directory of your website?

Comment: I suspect it is a couple of things.  The .htaccess is not been read, and you have not enabled mod_rewrite, can you confirm you have an .htaccesss in the root directory?

Comment: You saved my life. .htaccess was missing. Now as you can see at least i receive php errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For frameworks to handle URL paths two things have to be in place:

1. An **.htaccess** file with the appropriate rewrite rules or rewrite rules in the main apache configuration.
2. Mod_rewrite has to be enabled.

How to enable mod_rewrite:
[How to enable mod_rewrite for Apache 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2)

Rewrite Rules:
[Apache rewrite rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755065/apache-rewrite-rule)

For more information read the Apache HTTP Documentation